# Adding options in select tag generated from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my ajax code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#right_make').change(function() {
      var make = document.getElementById('right_make').value;
      alert(make);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'get.php',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
         data: {make:make},
         dataType: "html",
        type:'post',
        success: function (result) {
          var select = document.getElementById('right_model');

        select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', result);
           }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

I am getting data in form of html reverted from backend php ,I want to append this data in select tag ,given below

```
<select name="model" id="right_model" class="custom-select c_model right_model">
    <option value="">Model</option>
</select>
```

I tried the above thing but it is producing gaps between the options ,
this is what I am appending from backend

```
<?php

include 'includes/config.php';
include 'includes/database.php';
$make=$_POST['make'];

$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT distinct  `model` FROM `car` WHERE make=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$make);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($model);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<option>".$model."<option>";
}
?>
```

Any idea ow to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *it is producing gaps between the options*

Comment: something like and empty option ,after every non empty option

Comment: for that make sure you don't have empty  echo or print_r in any of file. As well as there is no space before and after `<?php` tags

Comment: yeah ,there was a gap !!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want to communicate some data with a php server, you may use JSON.

JSON keeps a very sample solution to traduce javascript or php to a very sample string. After, you can traduce JSON to php, Javascript or what else...

You may do this because php do not understand javascript and javascript do not understand php, of course.

When you pass data with your ajax, you may do like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'get.php',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
         data: {make:JSON.stringify (make)},      // Traduce to simply string.
         dataType: "html",
        type:'post',
        success: function (result) {
          var select = document.getElementById('right_model');

        select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', result);
           }
      });
```

Then, when you get the data in your php, you may do like this:

```
$make=json_decode ($_POST['make']);    // Traduce to php.
```

When you use echo:

```
echo json_encode ("<option>".$model."<option>");
```

And finally in your javascript:

```
success: function (result) {
      var select = document.getElementById('right_model');

    select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', JSON.parse (result));
       }
```

Consult the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).